# Как получить массив диапазонов из массива чисел? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть строка длиной 28 символов и есть массив чисел [3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25] - это те символы, которые надо выделить. Задача сделать из это массива - массив диапазонов следующего вида:

[ [0, 2, false], [3, 5, true], [6, 17, false], [18, 21, true], [22, 22, false], [23, 25, true], [26, 27, false] ]

Подскажите как получить такие диапазоны?

Comment: Уточните правила формирования массива, сейчас не понятно, как строка из 28-ми символов связана с этим массивом. Также приложите свою попытку решить задачу и что конкретно у вас не получается. Решать задачи за вас никто не собирается.

Comment: По какому алгоритму вставляется  true/false?  просто каждый новый меняет на противоположный или это с чем-то сверяется* И причем тут строка, что это за строка вообще?

Answer (score 3):

При чем здесь "строка" и какие-то "символы" - совершенно непонятно.

```js
const indices = [3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25];
const a = Array(28).fill(false);
indices.forEach(i => a[i] = true);

const ranges = [];
for (let i = 1, start = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] != a[start]) {
    ranges.push([start, i - 1, a[start]]);
    start = i;
  }
}

console.log(ranges);
```